# A calculator with support for large integers and variables

Tags: java, object-oriented, calculator

I'm quite new to both Java and OOP.

I'm assuming that pretty much everything about my code can be improved and I appreciate any feedback.  However, I am particularly interested in what you think about my code clarity/structure/organisation. For example, I've struggled to decide when functionality should be extracted into their own separate class ever since I've started with Java, so feedback on that would help me a lot.

This is also my first time including any error handling, what do you think of my efforts in  that regard?

My classes are also be seen on github [here](https://github.com/BLBaylis/Smart_Calculator).  I'm also not sure how much code is correct to post inside this question.  What happens if it is too much code to reasonably include in the post?  How large could projects posted to this forum be?

Thanks

#### Main.java

```
package calculator;

public class Main {

    private Main() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        calc.run();
    }
}
```

#### Calculator.java

```
package calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Calculator {
    private UserVariables userVariables = new UserVariables();

    Calculator() {
    }

    enum InputType {
        COMMAND, ASSIGNMENT, CALCULATION
    }

    private String getCommandMessage(String command) {
        if ("/exit".equals(command)) {
            return "Bye!";
        } else if ("/help".equals(command)) {
            return "Type in a calculation with spaces between each number and operator";
        } else {
            return "Unknown command";
        }
    }

    private InputType determineInputType(String userInput) {
        if (userInput.charAt(0) == '/') {
            return InputType.COMMAND;
        }
        Matcher assignmentMatcher = Pattern.compile("=").matcher(userInput);
        if (assignmentMatcher.find()) {
            return InputType.ASSIGNMENT;
        }
        return InputType.CALCULATION;
    }

    final void run() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
            if (userInput.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            InputType inputType = determineInputType(userInput);
            switch (inputType) {
                case COMMAND:
                    String message = getCommandMessage(userInput);
                    System.out.println(message);
                    if ("\\exit".equals(userInput)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    break;
                case ASSIGNMENT:
                    try {
                        userVariables.assignVariable(userInput);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;
                case CALCULATION:
                    try {
                        System.out.println(new Calculation(userInput).getResult());
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Calculation.java

```
package calculator;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;

class Calculation {
    private String result;
    private final static String operatorPrecededByOperandRegex = "(?<=\\w)(?=([-+*^/]))";
    private final static String operatorFollowedByOperandRegex = "(?<=[-+*^/])(?=\\w)";
    private final static String anyBracketRegex = "(?<=[()])|(?=[()])";

    Calculation(String inputString) {
        this.result = performCalculation(inputString);
    }

    String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    private String performCalculation(String inputString) {
        String validSingleOperandRegex = String.format("%s*(\\w+|\\d+)", "[+-]");
        boolean hasOneOperand = inputString.matches(validSingleOperandRegex);
        if (hasOneOperand) {
            String variableValue = UserVariables.get(inputString);
            return result = variableValue == null ? inputString : variableValue;
        }
        String[] inputArr = processInputString(inputString);
        Deque<String> notationQueue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Deque<String> operatorStack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        convertInfixToPostfix(inputArr, notationQueue, operatorStack);
        Deque<String> calcStack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        return calculatePostfixExpression(notationQueue, calcStack);
    }

    private String[] processInputString(String inputString) {
        String spacesRemovedInputString = inputString.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        /*The three regular expressions that comprise this regex each have zero width meaning that they are empty
         and instead these regexps just check for a condition to be true.  The reason for this is so when the inputString
         is split, none of the elements we are looking for are removed from the array in the process.
        */
        String stringSplitRegex = String.format("(%s|%s|%s)",
                operatorPrecededByOperandRegex,
                operatorFollowedByOperandRegex,
                anyBracketRegex
        );
        String[] inputArr = spacesRemovedInputString.split(stringSplitRegex);
        String[] substitutedArr = substituteVariables(inputArr);
        return fixOperators(substitutedArr);
    }

    static private String[] substituteVariables(String[] inputArr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i += 2) {
            if (UserVariables.containsKey(inputArr[i])) {
                inputArr[i] = UserVariables.get(inputArr[i]);
            }
        }
        return inputArr;
    }

    static private String[] fixOperators(String[] inputArr) {
        for (int i = 1; i < inputArr.length; i += 1) {
            if (inputArr[i].matches("[+-]+")) {
                inputArr[i] = Operator.parseOperator(inputArr[i]);
            }
        }
        return inputArr;
    }

    private void convertInfixToPostfix(String[] inputArr, Deque<String> notationQueue, Deque<String> operatorStack) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        for (String currInput : inputArr) {
            boolean nextOperatorOnOperatorStackIsOpeningBracket = "(".equals(operatorStack.peekFirst());
            boolean currInputIsOpeningBracket = "(".equals(currInput);
            if (currInput.matches("[+-]*\\d+")) {
                //if curr input is operand, add to notation queue
                notationQueue.addLast(currInput);
            } else if (operatorStack.isEmpty() || nextOperatorOnOperatorStackIsOpeningBracket || currInputIsOpeningBracket) {
                    operatorStack.addFirst(currInput);
            } else if (")".equals(currInput)) {
                /*If the current input is a closing bracket, pop from operator stack and push those onto notation queue
                until an opening bracket is found.  Neither the opening or closing bracket is added to the notation
                queue.*/
                handleClosingBracket(notationQueue, operatorStack);
            } else {
                /*If none of the above conditions are true, then that means the current input is an operator with a
                lower priority than the operator that is next on the operator stack.  At this point, the stack is popped
                until this is no longer the case, then the new operator is pushed onto the same stack*/
                handleLowerPriorityOperator(currInput, notationQueue, operatorStack);
            }
        }

        /*Once all inputs have been checked, add any remaining operators on stack to end of notation queue*/
        while (!operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
            String next = operatorStack.removeFirst();
            if ("(".equals(next) || ")".equals(next)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid expression");
            }
            notationQueue.addLast(next);
        }
    }

    private void handleClosingBracket(Deque<String> notationQueue, Deque<String> operatorStack) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        boolean openingBracketPopped = false;
        while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() && !openingBracketPopped) {
            String nextOperator = operatorStack.removeFirst();
            if ("(".equals(nextOperator)) {
                openingBracketPopped = true;
            } else {
                //add anything that isn't an opening bracket to notationStack
                notationQueue.addLast(nextOperator);
            }
        }
        if (!openingBracketPopped) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid expression");
        }
    }

    private void handleLowerPriorityOperator(String operator, Deque<String> notationQueue, Deque<String> operatorStack) {
        int operatorPriority = Operator.getOperatorPriority(operator);
        assert operatorStack.peekFirst() != null;
        String stackOperator = operatorStack.peekFirst();
        int stackOperatorPriority = Operator.getOperatorPriority(stackOperator);
        while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() && operatorPriority <= stackOperatorPriority) {
            notationQueue.addLast(operatorStack.removeFirst());
            if ("(".equals(operatorStack.peekFirst())) {
                break;
            }
            stackOperatorPriority = operatorStack.isEmpty() ? 0 : Operator.getOperatorPriority(operatorStack.peekFirst());
        }
        operatorStack.addFirst(operator);
    }

    private String calculatePostfixExpression(Deque<String> notationQueue, Deque<String> calcStack) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        while (!notationQueue.isEmpty()) {
            String next = notationQueue.removeFirst();
            if (next.matches("[+-]?\\d+")) {
                calcStack.addFirst(next);
            } else {
                BigDecimal result;
                BigDecimal pop1 = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(calcStack.removeFirst()));
                BigDecimal pop2 = new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(calcStack.removeFirst()));
                switch (next) {
                    case "+":
                        result = pop1.add(pop2);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result = pop2.subtract(pop1);
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result = pop2.multiply(pop1);
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        result = pop2.divide(pop1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                        break;
                    case "^":
                        result = pop2.pow(pop1.intValue());
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Postfix expression contained character which is neither " +
                                "digit nor allowed operator");
                }
                calcStack.addFirst(result.toString());
            }
        }
        return calcStack.getFirst();
    }

}
```

#### Operator.java

```
package calculator;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Operator {
    static final private Pattern minusPattern = Pattern.compile("-");

    static String parseOperator(String operator) {
        if (operator.length() == 1) {
            return operator;
        }
        Matcher minusRegexMatcher = minusPattern.matcher(operator);
        int minusCount = 0;
        while (minusRegexMatcher.find()) {
            minusCount++;
        }
        return minusCount % 2 == 1 ? "-" : "+";
    }

    static int getOperatorPriority(String operator) {
        switch (operator) {
            case "^":
                return 3;
            case "*":
            case "/":
                return 2;
            case "+":
            case "-":
                return 1;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Operator");
        }
    }
}
```

#### UserVariables.java

```
package calculator;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class UserVariables {
    static private Map<String, String> userVariables = new HashMap<>();

    UserVariables(){
    }

    private static void put(String key, String value) {
        userVariables.put(key, value);
    }

    static String get(String key) {
        return userVariables.get(key);
    }

    static boolean containsKey(String key) {
        return userVariables.containsKey(key);
    }

    void assignVariable(String userInput) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        userInput = userInput.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        String[] assignmentArr = userInput.split("=");
        if (assignmentArr.length != 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid assignment");
        }
        String variableName = assignmentArr[0];
        Matcher validVariableNameMatcher = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+").matcher(variableName);
        if (!validVariableNameMatcher.matches()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid identifier");
        }
        try {
            String variableValue = new Calculation(assignmentArr[1]).getResult();
            UserVariables.put(variableName, variableValue);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid assignment");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to time constraints, I have only viewed the first two classes, here are my comments:

### Main.java

1. There is no need for a private default constructor, unless you explicitly want to prevent from calling that method (e.g. in a singleton design pattern)
2. In my eyes, the whole class is redundant. the `main()` method can be placed in `Calculator`. it is common practice to have a main method that initializes the class it resides in.

### Calculator.java

1. **inconsistency:** in `run()` the exit command's literal is `"\\exit"` while in `getCommandMessage()` it is `"/exit"` so not sure how to exist the program.
2. **Separation of Concerns:** Calculator class is responsible for reading input from console, parsing and validating, and write to the console. When you will want to evolve this program to have an html interface, you wil have to rewrite the entire class. According to the principle of [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), you should have separate classes for reading and writing input. this design allows for having the same `Calculator` to work with different sources of input and destinations of output.
3. **Make use of enums as classes:** Java enums are powerful constructs that allow to attach properties and behaviors (=methods) to the set of values. as a rule of thumb, every closed set of values should be expressed as an enum. in your case, you started fine with `InputType`, but what about the set of commands? . if you have a `Command` enum, you can assign `message` String property to every value (you can have an `UNKNOWN` command as well) and that can replace the whole `getCommandMessage()`.  regarding `determineInputType()`: you can assign a `Predicate<String>` to every enum value and apply that predicate to the input String.

here's an illustration of what I am talking about:

```
enum InputType {
    COMMAND((userInput) -> userInput.charAt(0) == '/'),
    ASSIGNMENT((userInput) -> userInput.indexOf("=") > -1),
    CALCULATION((userInput) -> true);  // must be last enum value

    Predicate<String> isUserInputApply;

    InputType(Predicate<String> isUserInputApply) {
        this.isUserInputApply = isUserInputApply;
    }

    public static InputType determineInputType(String userInput) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
            .filter(inType -> inType.isUserInputApply.test(userInput))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(CALCULATION);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Sharon Ben Asher, thanks for taking a look!  I think I've underestimated the usefulness of enum!  One question though, my main class is set up the way it is because I'm following the advice of this short article https://coderanch.com/wiki/660020/Main-Pain.  Do you disagree with this practice or I am applying it unnecessarily?

Comment: My advice was to move main *as is* into Calculator, so it remains short.

Comment: Ah, my mistake!